# How we can send the location messages using firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-maps

I want to send the location messages using firebase. like when user click on button it shows alert which message you want to send like audio,video,location.When user select the location from the given option it will call locationViewController and store the location in firebase.I've simple loaded the google map with marker pin point and defined the coordinates it's self not dynamically. InputActionSheet func that defined in chatViewController when user tap on choose button this function call and inside another function call that will call the functionality of location messages.But I'm confused how we get get coordinates dynamically when user taped on any location on google map and also it will show the marker when user tap.
SimpleViewController class for checking the functionality of google map it's working fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()
    let karachi = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 24.882752, longitude: 67.149848)
    let tandoAdam = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 25.76284, longitude: 68.66087)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupMap(title: "Karachi", subtitle: "Shah Faisal", karachi)
        self.setupMap(title: "TDM", subtitle: "AK H", tandoAdam)
        self.mapView.mapStyle(name:"darkTheme", type:"json")
    }
    
    func setupMap(title:String,subtitle:String,_ coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude:  coordinate.longitude, zoom: 6.0)
        mapView.camera = camera
        mapView.camera = camera
        self.addMarker(title: title, subtitle: subtitle, coordinate:coordinate)
    }
    
    func addMarker(title:String,subtitle:String,coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive")
        marker.position = coordinate
        marker.title = title
        marker.snippet = subtitle
        marker.map = mapView
    }

    
}
extension UIViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard locations.first != nil else{
            return
        }
    }

}
```

presentInputActionSheet func  in Chat class:

```
private func presentInputActionSheet() {
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Attach Media",
                                            message: "What would you like to attach?",
                                            preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Photo", style: .default, handler: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentPhotoInputActionsheet()
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Video", style: .default, handler: { [weak self]  _ in
            self?.presentVideoInputActionsheet()
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Audio", style: .default, handler: {  _ in

        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Location", style: .default, handler: { [weak self]  _ in
            self?.presentLocationPicker()
        }))
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        present(actionSheet, animated: true)
    }
```

presentLocationPicker func  in Chat class:

```
private func presentLocationPicker() {
        let vc = ViewController(coordinates: nil)
        vc.title = "Pick Location"
        vc.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
        let location = Location(location: CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude),
                                 size: .zero)
        let message = Message(sender: selfSender,messageId: messageId,sentDate: Date(),kind: .location(location))
            DatabaseManager.shared.sendMessage(to: conversationId, otherUserEmail: strongSelf.otherUserEmail, name: name, newMessage: message, completion: { success in
                if success {
                    print("sent location message")
                }
                else {
                    print("failed to send location message")
                }
            })
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Use the period to end each English sentence.

Comment: That last section of code in `presentLocationPicker` is going to be an issue. The `navigationController?.push` needs to be inside the `sendMessage` closure or else it will run *before* the code within the closure. Not an answer but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 let message = Message(sender: selfSender,messageId: messageId,sentDate: Date(),kind: .location(location))
            DatabaseManager.shared.sendMessage(to: conversationId, otherUserEmail: strongSelf.otherUserEmail, name: name, newMessage: message, completion: { success in
                if success {
                    print("sent location message")
                }
                else {
                    print("failed to send location message")
                }
                navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            })

        }
```

Comment: Kommuir I think you didn't get my point. The viewcontroller class where i defined the coordinates of two cities ok using Google map not map kit and load in the viewcontroller. Issue is that I want the fucntionality where when google map load and user click on any cities it shows the marker and stored in Cllocation ok